# NodeJs and ExpressJs Cannot Set Cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

Can you help me for creating cookies cause i can't make it work. I would like to set and create cookies after the user logs in but I don't know what's wrong with my codes. Thanks Guys.

Here's my code, if you think there's other error's or code correction can you help me fix it? Thanks guys. :)

**app.js**

```
//deps

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();


var delcookie = function(req, res) { res.clearCookie('login_token'); res.redirect('/');     };
var setcookie = function(req, res) { res.cookie('login_token', +new Date(), { maxAge: 3600000, path: '/' }); res.redirect('/'); };

//configs
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(app.router);

client.on('error', function (err) {
console.log('Error: ' + client.host + ':' + client.port + ' - ' + err);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/login/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/login.html');
});

app.get('/register/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/register.html');
});

app.get('/restricted/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/restricted.html');
});

app.get('/logout/', delcookie, function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/logout.html');
});

//post

app.post('/login/', function (req, res) {
//res.sendfile(__dirname + '/restricted.html');
client.hmget( req.body.user.username, 'password', function (err,pass) {
if ( (!err) && pass && pass == req.body.user.password ){
    res.redirect('/restricted/', setcookie);
    }   else if ( pass == false)   {
    res.redirect('/register/');
    }   else    {
    res.redirect('/login/');
    }
    });
});

app.post('/register/', function (req, res) {    
client.hmset(req.body.user.username, 'password',req.body.user.password, 
'fname',req.body.user.fname, 'lname', req.body.user.lname, 
'password', req.body.user.password, 'email', req.body.user.email,
'mobile', req.body.user.mobile, redis.print);
res.write('Successfully Registered');
});

app.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use cookies you should look at the Express `cookieSession` middleware. The docs are here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession

**Update** (I can't test it right now so this is from what I can remember):

You can add the cookieSession middleware and specify the settings for your cookie with something like:

```
app.use(express.cookieSession({
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 3600000
    }
}));
```

Then when your user logs in you can set the login token on the session with `req.session.login_token = 'login_token';`.

And when your user logs out you can clear the session by doing `req.session = null;`.

In your authentication middleware you can then check that the login token is set on the session to see if the user is authenticated.

Comment: I've already read that -_- but I still don't know how to make it work Brett.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.