# ExpressJS set/get/use cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

Cannot get setted cookies within requests.

I set my cookie with

```
response.cookie('name', 'My name');
```

I would like to get my cookie this way, and it worked before, but I changed express configuration, and I don't know what seems to be the problem now.

```
request.cookies is and empty Object
```

My express configuration:

```
var express = require('express'),
    api = require('./routes/api');

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
   app.use(express.favicon());
   app.use(express.logger('dev'));
   app.use(express.json());
   //app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.use(express.compress()); // New call to compress content
   app.use(express.cookieParser());
   app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret'}));
   app.use(app.router);
   app.use(express.methodOverride());
   //app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
    next();
});

app.configure('development', function () {
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function () {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

Setting Cookie:

```
exports.singIn = function (req, res) {
    var mail = req.query.mail,
        password = req.query.password;

    return user.find({
        mail: mail
    }).then(function (d) {
        var user = usersData(u);

        res.cookie('mail', user.mail, { maxAge: 900000});
        res.cookie('password', crypted, { maxAge: 900000});
        res.json({ user: user });
        return { user: user }
    }).catch(function () {
        res.json(400, {"error-tag": "error-sing-in"});
        return {"error-tag": "error-sing-in"};
    });
};
```

Getting Cookie:

```
exports.account = function (req, res) {
    var mail = req.cookies.mail,
        password = req.cookies.password;
    //here req.cookies is an empty object. I don't know why? 
};
```

Comment: How/where are you calling `"singIn`"?

Comment: I think you need to use the cookieSession middleware. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18510185/446681

Comment: singIn is called when user sing in with its main and password. account is used, when getting all the data of a user.

Comment: if i add app.use(express.cookieSession({
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 3600000
    }
}));


i get this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:3000/oauth/sing/in?mail=da@da.da&password=dada. Origin http://localhost:4400 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: i needed a secret in cookieSession: app.use(express.cookieSession({ secret: 'tobo!', cookie: { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 }})); but still no success :(

Comment: I am not able to understand your code. "var user = usersData(u);" in this line, what is the value of 'u'? Where is it come from?

Comment: are you sure about Javascript scope in your code?

Comment: Is this question still alive? It appears that the user **hasn't included the sign-in module**, and even if they had, there is a potential `typo` with the method name `singIn`

Answer (score 22):

An answer for 2017 ..

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
```

to get a cookie from an incoming request ..

```
let cookie = req.cookies['cookiename'];
```

to set a response cookie (this cookie will be sent on all future incoming requests until deletion or expiration) ..

```
res.cookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue', {
    maxAge: 86400 * 1000, // 24 hours
    httpOnly: true, // http only, prevents JavaScript cookie access
    secure: true // cookie must be sent over https / ssl
});
```

to delete a response cookie ..

```
res.cookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue', {
    maxAge: 0
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It's kind of exaggerated to use an extra package ("cookie-parser"), when this is the middleware function you need:

```
function cookieParser(req, res, next) {
  var cookies = req.headers.cookie;
  if (cookies) {
    req.cookies = cookies.split(";").reduce((obj, c) => {
      var n = c.split("=");
      obj[n[0].trim()] = n[1].trim();
      return obj
    }, {})
  }
  next();
}
app.use(cookieParser);
```

I couldn't use "cookie-parser" in my graphQL server because it was messing things up.

Comment: "Everything is just a header, bro" approach isn't very useful either. This kind of manual parsing breaks when strings with `";"`/`"="` are used in the values (with encoding on top).