# React - How to send a cookie along fetch and get it in the backend NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I have a project where I set a cookie with universal-cookie.

```
cookies.set('auth-token', data);
```

I then have a fetch request:

```
  const getMeals = async (date: Date) => {
    let res= await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/meals/", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        date: date
      }),
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    console.log(data);
  }
```

And a backend where it gets checked (NodeJs, ExpressJs):

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    const token = req.header('auth-token');
    if(!token){
        return res.status(401).json('Access denied!');
    }
}
```

I see the cookie in my mozilla:

[image]

But I always get "Access denied!" -> that means the auth-token is not there...
I hardcoded the auth-token into the fetch and it worked.

I checked several websites and almost all stackoverflow posts on this theme. I also checked the fetch-api documentation, but I couldnt come up with a solution...

Both the client and the server are running on localhost.

I hope someone can help me with this topic.

**UPDATE**

Andreas suggested that I should either set the header(frontend) or look for cookie- instead of header-values(backend).

I decided to do the second approach.

Server.js

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users'); //where auth.js gets imported

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

I tried changing the position of `app.use(cookieParser());` to above all others - didnt help.

auth.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    const cookie = req.cookies['auth-token'];
    console.log(cookie);
}
```

The problem I now have is that the cookie value is `undefined` even though the cookie gets displayed in FireFox.

I tried to do the steps [of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591689/expressjs-set-get-use-cookies), but this doesnt work afterwards I went to their official documentation and found nothing.
I also stumbled upon [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720801/why-is-req-cookies-undefined), which makes me think that something is wrong in the frontend...

Frontend-File where I set the cookie:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const login = async () => {
        let res= await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: (e.target as HTMLFormElement).email.value,
            password: (e.target as HTMLFormElement).password.value,
          }),
        });
    
        const data = await res.json()
        
        if(res.status === 200){
          cookies.set('auth-token', data);
          setUserId((jwt_decode(data) as any)._id);
          navigate("/");
        }else{
          alert(data);
        }
}
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: A cookie is not magically converted into a header value with the same name (`.header('auth-token')`). You would have to add the header manually like the `Content-Type`

Comment: if you are setting cookie, you can check in req object as req.cookie['cookieName']. You need to add cookie parser to read it.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I already tried this, but it didnt find anything.

Comment: @Andreas so i should set an extra value in the header with the name ´auth-token` and set the value to the cookie content?

But isnt this the thing why I would use a cookie, because it gets send with every request automatically?

Comment: It depends... Your server is looking for a header and not a cookie. Either adjust the request (set the header) or the server (look for a cookie and not a header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix the problem with the help of a friend. I had to add `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"` to my `package.json` in my React-Project, because the port is important for the cookie so **localhost:5000** and **localhost:3000** are **not the same** for it. I could also remove the `app.use(cors())` from my NodeJs-Project, because of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you run your front end on http://127.0.0.1:3000. If you are already doing that then you have to call fetch with credentials options set to include.
This is because unless fetch() is called with the credentials option set to include, fetch():

1. won't send cookies in cross-origin requests
2. won't set any cookies sent back in cross-origin responses
   As of August 2018, the default credentials policy changed to same-origin. Firefox was also modified in version 61.0b13)

Comment: My frontend is on 3000, my backend is on 5000.

Comment: to to  to add the option credentials: "include" to fetch

Comment: didnt work for me sadly, ive already answered, but i can only make it the official answer tomorrow.